# How to make border layout center region infinite scrolling?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working in extjs4.And I have a task there I am going to work on border layout.I want to make my border layout center region get infinite scrolled i.e. it loading child components in center region at that time my footer goes on downward direction based on child components.How can I create this with border layout? Is it possible with border layout ? I worked and searched a lot on it but not getting solution.Please give me some suggestions...
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.keep config  scroll:vertical for the center panel.Can you properly interpret your question,I mean what your trying to achieve.I have understood only that you want a border layout with header,center and footer region.I mean where you are facing issue?